# how to find something from a list in a text file

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

```
with open ("patientlist.txt","r") as file:
    patientlist = [line.split(",")for line in file]
for patient in patientlist:
    patient[-1] = patient[-1].replace('\n',"")

def medicine():
    health=input("choose the medicine you want to display clients for")
    vMember=False
    while vMember==False:
        for m in patientlist:
            if m[0] == health:
                vMember=True
```

From here, what could I add so that from a list in a text file (`patientlist`) you could display everyone who uses an 'inhaler' in a list, with their age in another column, e.g.,

```
paul,50,antidepressants
liz,24,inhaler
jack,30,epipen
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Where is patientlist defined? Can you display a bit of the formatting of the text file from which you parse the information?

Comment: Given an input of `inhaler` you want to display all the information related to it? Like Names associated with it, then the information of those people?

Comment: with open ("patientlist.txt","r") as file:
    patientlist=[line.split(",")for line in file]
for patient in patientlist:
    client[-1]=client[-1].replace('\n',"")

Comment: Edit your question to include a sample of what the text file looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list and display(use) that record. No need for using the variable **vMember**. Use of **vMember** in the way you did will stop iteration on first occurrence of the patient using 'inhaler'.

```
def medicine():
    health=input("choose the medicine you want to display clients for")
    for m in patientlist:
        if m[2] == health:    # Note, change of m[0](name) to m[2](health)
            print m
```